# Is there a map between MDN "Experimental" and TC39 stages?

Tags: javascript

On Mozilla Developers Network, there are documented Javascript APIs which are marked as "Experimental". Digging into Mozilla's documentation, I found [this page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/MDN/Contribute/Guidelines/Conventions_definitions#Experimental) which describes what that means, but it doesn't reference TC39 at all. Googling the API's name plus "TC39" returned nothing of value.

My understanding is that TC39, not Mozilla, define what is "Javascript" (ecmascript) and have a strict definition for "Experimental", based around the Stages. Is there any way to translate between Mozilla's notation and the TC39 Stage?

Comment: Mozilla documents lots of web technologies, not just EcmaScript. Usually whatever documentation you are reading, it does link the current standard, which in the case of a TC39 proposal will include the current stage.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer seems clear based on the information available via the link in your question. Mozilla will mark something as experimental if either:

> Its defining spec is not stable and likely to change significantly [...]

or if

> It is implemented and enabled by default in less than two modern major browsers.

So no, although the TC39 stage likely determines the first of those two criteria (at least for technologies that are part of ECMAScript), overall Mozilla's designation doesn't *necessarily* map directly to a TC39 stage. It's a classification they apply to a range of web technologies based on a combination of factors of their own determination.

Answer (score 1):

MDN encompasses documentation for a variety of web-related technologies. It's important to remember the distinction between ECMAScript (the JavaScript language) and the DOM/Browser APIs it interacts with. **TC39** is specifically concerned with additions to the syntax of the language itself (like, for instance, the [Pipeline](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Pipeline_operator) operator). Compare this with something like [`window.caches`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/caches), which is specified by the **w3c**. While they are both considered experimental by MDN (and marked as such), only experimental syntax and actual language features will be traceable to TC39, and this is usually noted in the "Specification" section of the documentation for that syntax, feature or API.